# Regexp: match quotes, that are not in substitution

Tags: python, regex

My template engine translates

```
"some data #{substitution_expression} some other data"
```

into

```
"some data" + (substitution_expression) + "some other data"
```

But if "some data" or "some other data" would have double quotes inside, the evalution fails.
I have to add slashes before these quotes, but I can not come up with the right regular expression for that.

Any help?

UPDATE:

This is how the template engine works:

1. It gets a template string, e.g.

   ```
   template = 'template string "quoted text" #{expression}'
   ```
2. It changes the template string by a simple regexp to:

   ```
   template = '"%s"' % re.compile(r'\#{(.*)}').match(r'" + (\1) + "', template)  
   # template == "template string "quoted text"" + (expression) + ""  
   # here is a problem with a "quoted text" - it needs \ before quotes`
   ```
3. This string is being inserted into lambda, and the result code string is being evaled:

   ```
   return eval("lambda tpl_args: %s" % modified_template_string)
   ```
4. The lambda is being called later at the program with some tpl_args to generate a result string.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you describe what doesn't work in the same way you described what does? What is the string you have and what do you want to match?

Comment: You should throw some more light on how your template engine works. Perhaps show us some more code if possible.

Comment: What is the code you are using now?

Comment: It doesn't really sound like you need a regex, just a string replace function: " with \" - that will depend on what language you're using.

Comment: Ashwini, no. This is pure Python.

Comment: What Tony said ... but what you posted above looks like a static string, so I'm uncertain as to how you'd manipulate that before passing it into whatever your template engine is.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope I was able to explain more clearly

Comment: Also very unclear on this.  What exactly is your question?  What are you using the regular expression to look for?

Comment: I look for a regular expression to replace quotes in the quoted text only (not in #{} sections) with slashed quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the re.DOTALL flag?

```
re.compile(r'\#{(.*)}', re.DOTALL)
```